# highcharts IE9 vs IE8

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi I have built a highchart 2.1.4 graph.
the tooltip acts differently in IE9 and IE8.

[image: IE9]

[image: IE8]

the code for the tooltip is

```
formatter: function()
                    {

                            return 'Time: ' +Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>'+
                            '<b>' + titletootip +': ' +this.y +  '</b>'+'<br/>'+
                            'Change: ' +this.point.config[2] ;

                    }
```

how do I fix this?

thanks.

edit:

i have upgraded highcharts to 2.3.1 and also jquery to 1.8.1.
Had to fix a small error and now it works in every browser. 
thanks, guys.

now, I want to make it with colors.. but this is another issue...

Comment: thanks. it's 2.1.4. can't use any higher due to jquery 1.4.4.

Comment: @devmonster can you create example in jsFiddle?

Comment: i have upgraded highcharts to 2.3.1 and also jquery to 1.8.1. Had to fix a small error and now it works in every browser. thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to explicitly set [tooltip.useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.useHTML) to true

As a confirmation try [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/footerformat/) in both the browsers and check for consistency